# Overheating LED lamp

Tags: power-supply, led, resistors

I purchased a cheap battery head mounted led lamp containing 24 white led's. It is powered by 3 x AA batteries (1.2v each) in series producing approx 3.6v, It works fine when powered from batteries but I had intended to use it along with others to illuminate a terrarium using a converted computer ATX switched power supply's 3.3v rail. It worked but after a few minutes the molded plastic mirror reflector started to crackle and deform as the printed circuit board the led's are soldered to became very hot. My question is Why do they overheat when using a power supply but not when using batteries and what would I need to do to prevent them from overheating when powered by the ATX supply ? Im sure this is a resistance issue but just can't get my head around this one.     Thanks in advance.

Comment: The batteries have an internal resistance.  Apparently the design relied on it...

Comment: @bitsmack: You beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

What @bitsmack refers to is very common in cheap devices, also like camera flashers of olden times. Usually a non-chip resonator that converts the incoming voltage is current limited by the battery internal resistance. For 3AA in series start with trying around the 3 to 4 Ohm mark.

Do mind, though, that you should measure the current with a multimeter with the batteries and with the resistor, and try to keep within a 10% margin around fresh batteries when choosing the final resistor.

But, never exclude the possibility you accidentally used the 5V rail either. Check everything!

Comment: The wrong rail suggestion made me chuckle, that was what I  had first suspected and  checked, I was using the 3.3v rail (orange on an ATX supply) Can I expect the resistor to get hot and therefore use a ceramic one ?

Answer (score 0):

Since AA Batteries have about 1 ohm internal resistance, 3 ohms makes sense.

Since most white LEDs need about 3 mA to turn on, and about 10 mA to look decent, lets do a few quick calculations:

If the LEDs draw 3mA each with 3 ohms in place:

3mA * 24 = 72mA

That will equate with a voltage drop across the resistor of .216V, so the LEDS will get 3.1V. The power dissipated in the resistor will be I²*R, so 16mW, about 1/64th watt, hardly anything.

3.1V will probably make the LEDS draw more current than 3mA, so let's try 10mA:

10mA * 24 = 240mA

That will equate with a voltage drop across the resistor of .72V, so the LEDS will get 2.58V. The power dissipated in the resistor will be I²*R, so 173mW, about 1/6th watt, so a regular 1/2 watt resistor would be fine.

Since most white LEDS need about 2.7 volts to really turn on and draw current, 3 ohms should work fine and not need to be ceramic.

However, It is still good to measure the voltage drop across the resistor to make sure it will be okay.